# Rails - multiple relationships between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relationships

1. A user can teach many topics, and each topic can have many lessons.
2. A user can join lessons created by other users.

(1) is pretty simple and I implemented it as follow:

```
#user.rb
has_many :topics
has_many :lessons, through: :topic

#topic.rb
has_many :lessons

#lesson.rb
belongs_to :topic
belongs_to :user
```

(2) is a many-to-many relationships and I think a join table - let's call it matches (extra points to help me find a better name!) - is required.

If I add the following

```
#user.rb
.
.
has_many :lessons, through: :match

#lesson.rb
.
.
has_many :users, through: :match

#match.rb
belongs_to :lesson
belongs_to :user
```

I think I will get an error since Rails cannot get the difference between the two relationships while calling @user.lessons, for example.

What can be a correct approach?

**p.s.** I see there are many questions similar to this one but I was not able to find a proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should name the join table `user_lessons` rather than match being a convention in Rails for join tables.
After renaming, I think you should rather have it like this:

user.rb

```
   has_many :user_lessons
   has_many :subscribed_lessons, through: :user_lessons, source: :lesson
```

Also note that your user

```
has_many :lessons, through: :topics #not :topic
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: thanks oreoluwa, your answer makes lot of sense. I'll test it and will let you know, but I think it's the correct way. Thanks for the tip on naming, I'll follow your advice. The missing 's' on topics was a typo, but thank you for pointing it out :) If then I need something like lesson.subscribed_users to see the list of subscribers I guess I shall add `has_many :subscribed_users, through :user_lessons, source: :users` to lesson.rb, right?

Comment: I guess so. Note that your source ought to be `user` not `users`